# Combobox focus, killing combobox focus

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, combobox

How to check if the combobox is focused? and how too kill the focus?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement an override for  Method ON_CBN_SETFOCUS:

This is called when the combobox gets the focus.

to kill the focus I don't really know an method, but you could just set the focus to an other control or the dialog from within the "SetFocus" Method.